# Numerical problems in Matlab: Same input, same code -> different output?

Tags: matlab, numerical

I am experiencing problems when I compare results from different runs of my Matlab software with the same input. To narrow the problem, I did the following:

- save all relevant variables using Matlab's save() method
- call a method which calculates something
- save all relevant output variables again using save()

Without changing the called method, I did another run with

- load the variables saved above and compare with the current input variables using isequal()
- call my method again with the current input variables
- load the out variables saved above and compare.

I can't believe the comparison in the last "line" detects slight differences. The calculations include single and double precision numbers, the error is in the magnitude of 1e-10 (the output is a double number).

The only possible explanation I could imagine is that either Matlab looses some precision when saving the variables (which I consider very unlikely, I use the default binary Matlab format) or that there are calculations included like a=b+c+d, which can be calculated as a=(b+c)+d or a=b+(c+d) which might lead to numerical differences.

Do you know what might be the reason for the observations described above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example for that? It can be highly dependent on which functions you use. Differences are common if any function in the path uses some randomness. Probably this is not the case, but a reproducable example would still give others something to work with.

Comment: unfortunately the method I invoke involves many computation steps and even some code I cannot share. I was just wondering if this behaviour is "valid Matlab behaviour" or if it points to a problem in my code. There are some randn() calls involved, but the RandStream is set before each run, so it produces the same value. And it seems like after eliminating the single precision numbers from the code eliminates the appearance of the problem (or makes it less likely??)

Comment: This is very unexpected behavior from MATLAB. Is it possible that the difference occurs when you save your variables? You say you load the variables and compare--what about saving the results of both runs, and comparing those saved results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really seems to be caused by the single/double mix in the calculations. Since I have switched to double precision only, the problem did not occur anymore. Thanks to everybody for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

these could be rounding errors. you can find the floating point accuracy of you system like so:

```
>> eps('single')

ans =

  1.1921e-07
```

On my system this reports 10^-7 which would explain discrepancies of your order

Comment: but shouldn't rounding always return the same value? Or does it depend on "indeterministic" factors?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure reproducible results, especially if you are using any random generating functions (either directly or indirectly), you should restore the same state at the beginning of each run:

```
%# save state (do this once)
defaultStream = RandStream.getDefaultStream;
savedState = defaultStream.State;
save rndStream.mat savedState

%# load state (do this at before each run)
load rndStream.mat savedState
defaultStream = RandStream.getDefaultStream();
defaultStream.State = savedState;
```

Comment: I do stream0 = RandStream('mrg32k3a','Seed',myConstantSeed);    RandStream.setDefaultStream(stream0); before each run. This should be working too, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes its the same thing, only using a seed to initialize the state.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to try to compare the results of two saved runs (in case save/load are introducing some loss of precision) as @AlexFeinman suggests in the comments above..